# Offline English-German dictionary for Android

Tags: gratis, android, offline, translation, dictionary

A friend asked for this and I don't have an answer.

Must be:

- Android
- Gratis
- Offline, with complete dictionary in SD card

Nice to have:

- large vocabulary
- declension & conjugation in both languages (bring/brung/brought & bringgen/brachte/gebracht)
- easy to add other dictionaries & hopefully to translate between them & English and/or German
  (note that if we add e.g French & Spanisch, we want to translate between those and English/German, but not between French/Spanish, if you see what I mean (no babel fisch))

Comment: Can't you save a Google Translate dictionary? You are able to do that for languages

Comment: If so, please post an an answer saying how.

Comment: Install Google Translate, then follow this page to download languages so translation can happen offline https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142473?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I will accept it. Note that, when I installed, it asked for my primary and most translated languages - and then asked if I should install that for offline use. I love Google Translate for its ability to translate text in pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give **Google Translate** a go, [available on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate&hl=en) and is totally free.

Once installed, you can follow instructions from the [official guide](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142473?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en):

> ### Choose and download languages
>
> 1. Make sure you’re connected to a Wi-Fi network.
> 2. Open the Translate app.
> 3. On either side of the screen, tap the language at the top.
> 4. Right next to the language you want to download, tap Download. If it’s not there, the language can’t be downloaded.
> 5. When prompted to download the language file, tap Download.
>
> Next to each language saved on your device, you’ll see Downloaded.
>
> ### Download languages without Wi-Fi
>
> You can tell Translate to download languages without needing access to a Wi-Fi network. This may impact your data plan.
>
> 1. Open the Translate app.
> 2. Tap Menu.
> 3. Tap Settings.
> 4. Tap Data usage.
> 5. Tap Download offline translation files.
>
>    - To always be asked before downloading a language off Wi-Fi, tap Ask before downloading.
>    - To use your data plan, tap Use Wi-Fi or mobile network.

Comment: When I installed, it asked for my primary and most translated languages - and then asked if I should install that for offline use. I love Google Translate for its ability to translate text in pictures.

Answer (score 3):

May I recommend my favorite dictionary app to you: **[ColorDict Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.colordict)**. First, how it meets your requirements:

- **Android:** Sure.
- **Gratis:** Yes.
- **Offline:** Yes, but also supports Online lookups
- **complete dictionary in SD card:** After you told the app to save it there, yes. Selection and download from within the app. Supports a ton of formats (e.g. StarDict), so there's a good selection. And yes, I'm using it with EN/DE as well as with EN/EN and more.

Now for the goodies you didn't ask for:

- you can use this as stand-alone dictionary
- you can use it to lookup terms you marked in another app: I do so in *Moon+ Reader*, and it gives you a nice overlay with your terms and translations.

Answer (score 2):

[Offline dictionaries](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.nghs.android.dictionnaires&hl=en)

requirements

- free
- offline (must download dictionary packs first)
- can customize where the dictionaries are saved

bonus

- very powerful dictionaries/thesaurus available
- many translating dictionaries available
- supports text to speech (most dictionaries I've used do too though)

Out of all the dictionaries I've tried, this is my go to dictionary. Even though every single language isn't available yet, this dictionary makes going through available language packs easy as you can use it as much as you want offline, and avoid roaming charges.

Answer (score -1):

Once your friend gets a bit comfortabel with the German language he could use [Livio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.de_DE&hl=en). It is a monolingual German dictionary, so no English. Definitions are based on Wiktionary. It is my preferred offline app for looking up German words.

Comment: As the OP, I did not downvote this, but I can undertsand why someone did. Simpe rule - if it doesn't answer the question, then it is a comment.

Comment: I was going to do that, but I do not have enough reputation to post a comment...

Comment: Than I have upvoted it, although it is still not a good answer ;-) I hope that this won't put you off and that you will continue to participate in the group. WIlkommen an Bord !

Comment: Dankeschön! :-)

Comment: Keine Ursache :-)